# How to get minimal value of Array in Julia?

Tags: julia

How do I get the minimum value of an `Array`, `Vector`, or `Matrix` in Julia?

The code `min([1, 2, 3])` doesn't work.

Comment: Use `minimum`, not `min`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**The Julia manual:**
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.min

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.minimum

min(x, y, ...)

Return the minimum of the arguments. Operates elementwise over arrays.

```
julia> min([1, 2, 3]...)
1

julia> min(2,3)
2
```

minimum(A, dims)

Compute the minimum value of an array over the given dimensions.

minimum!(r, A)

Compute the minimum value of A over the singleton dimensions of r, and write results to r.

```
julia> minimum([1, 2, 3])
1
```

Comment: The answer to the original question is rather hidden in your answer. Certainly give a reference to the manual, but don't just copy it here.

Comment: And for completeness (and future readers) examples are good, for example, `min([1,2],[3,0])` for elementwise `min`, etc.

Comment: min([1,2],[3,0])  is deprecated. Now one should use min.([1,2],[3,0])

Comment: The link in the answer is now dead. Correct link is https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/collections/

Comment: The right link to the function `minimum`, as of 1.1, is currently https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/collections/#Base.minimum

Comment: All the links in the comments are dead now. (error 404)